# Replacing Team names with their logos in a table

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a script that pulls data form MySQL and arranges it in a table but I want the Team 1, Team 2, and Organizer outputs within my  tags to be replaced with an image stored on my web server but I have no clue how to do this

**My Script:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ECmatches");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Team 1</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  <th>Team 2</th>
  <th>Best Of</th>
  <th>Maps</th>
  <th>Organizer</th>
  <th>Match Time</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['MatchID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Team1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Team2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Series'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Maps'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Organizer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['MatchTime'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Have you got team name to logo mapping defined anywhere?

Comment: Not at the moment, I'm not 100% sure how to do that

Comment: You then need to define/store the mappings between teams and logo urls somewhere (maybe database). You can then read the corresponding columns from db and display the logos.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using the team's unique id in the filename (eg `/team-img/1.jpg`), and then using php and mysql to get that:

```php
<img src="/team-img/<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg">
```